# NodeJS process.stdin `end` event breaks http.server action

Tags: events, process, node.js, eval, stdin

I am creating a little program that read the STDIN and and increment a string with each data chunk, like this:

```
var fullchunk;

process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8');

process.stdin.on('data', function (chunk) {

    if (!fullchunk) {
        fullchunk = "";
    }

    fullchunk += chunk;

});

process.stdin.once('end', function () {

   process.stdin.removeAllListeners('data');
   eval(fullchunk);

});
```

but somehow It seems I can't use the `end` event here because when the text I send through stdin is something like a http server it won't run properly, but it works well if I only use the `onData` event without declaring anything inside the `end` event.

```
//STDIN content

require("http").createServer(function(request, response) { 

    response.writeHead(200);
    response.end("Hello World");

}).listen(3000);
```

So this is definitely one thing I can't understand why a http server action keeps running with that but it's not responsive to my requests, not sure if this has anything with the variable scope which is inherited by the main function or if the `end` function cancel all the other requests.

Any help would be enormously appreciated :)

Comment: Maybe have a look at how this is handled using ChildProcess here: https://github.com/creationix/node-git/blob/master/lib/git-fs.js

Comment: Thanks a lot orangutancloud, it seems this is definitely the way to go , the only thing I can't understand is how to pass the `process.stdin` content to the child process I've just created. Should it be inherited automatically, otherwise the `child.stdin.on("data"...` won't fire?

Comment: One thing that might be worth to mention is that the program is being triggered by TextMate Text Editor as a Bundle, int this case TextMate sends the contents of the file currently opened as input. I am afraid there's no way to interfere with the process neither start a new one programatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this issue showed up when using Node `0.4.0` and gladly disappeared after upgrading to `0.4.3` and the http server can fortunately run fine after the `end` event is triggered.
One interesting thing tho, was to replace the `eval(fullchunk)` for the [`vm module`](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.2/api/vm.html#vm.runInNewContext), proving a finest implementation and result constrained to its own sandbox:

```
require("vm").runInNewContext(fullchunk, {require: require});
```

Hope somehow this can be useful